# How to add photo on Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, jobs

I am not able to add my photo on my Stack Overflow Careers profile. I checked the link and set photo there but I am not getting the photo here.

[image: stack overflow careers profile]

How can I add my pic? Here is my profile: [Md Mohsin](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/mdmohsin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Click "my profile" link:

   > [image]
2. Click the top "edit" link to the right of the current avatar:

   > [image]
3. Make sure that you have the correct email set and the "Display Gravatar" is ticked:

   > [image]
4. If needed, click "Save" to save changes.

Comment: i have problem in my gmail id...i am using jmi.mosin@gmail.com instead of jmi.mohsin@gmail.com ..i have created two accounts mistakenly...thanks to focus on this.

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

The pic the careers profile requires is gravatar pic.

Click it, then click "Create Your Own Gravatar". Assign this gravatar to the email you used to create your profile, receive the email, go to the link. Check the box "Display Gravatar" in your careers profile (you already did this step as I see). Now your careers profile has this pic!

Comment: where is the link "Create Your Own Gravatar" ..i checked "what is this?" link and set there pic but not getting here.

Comment: here is my profile on gravatar: https://en.gravatar.com/jmimohsin

Comment: @MdM did you use the same email in gravatar as in your careers profile?

Comment: yes i use only one email id everywhere that is jmi.mohsin@gmail.com